# Remove multiple values ​from a string c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a String example:

```
#5/r/n#12/r/n#23/r/n#43/r/n#54/r/n#23/r/n#77/r/n
```

I need to pass these values ​​to a list and get the values ​​between # and /r/n

So far I have the following code:

```
List<string> result = Regex.Split(String, @"/r/n").ToList();
```

This separates each value, leaving #, how can I remove #, to each value from the list?

Comment: What about replace?

Comment: Also split by `#` and remove empty entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one line using **LINQ**:

```
List<string> result = Regex.Split(String, @"/r/n").Select(s => s.Replace("#", "")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the trim function to remove special characters from the front and end of your strings.

```
myString.Trim( new Char[] { '#', ' '} )
```

User the string null or empty operator to cleanse any empty strings as well:

```
List<string> result = Regex.Split(myString, @"/r/n").Select(a => a.Trim(new Char[] { '#', ' ' })).Where(b => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(b)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use trim

```
char[] charsToTrim = { '#' };


List<string> result = Regex.Split(String, @"/r/n").
                      .Select(x => x.Trim(charsToTrim))
                      .ToList();
```

You could also split on the # and trim the other.  Which ever makes sense.

I believe that Trim will be faster than Replace -- but I did not test it.